# Element won't append to container

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm working on a simple blackjack game, where the dealer will be served one card and the player two (basic rules).

The cards display just fine, but when I append a class to the dealers card container, the container refuses to acknowledge the class I just appended. I copy and pasted the same code from my player function which deals the player cards successfully and that doesn't seem to work on my dealer function either.

The class I am trying to append is "symbol".

If you take a look at the jsfiddle snippet below, you can inspect it to see the class "symbol" doesn't get appended to dealer, but works completely fine in the player function.

Thank you in advance for the help.

http://jsfiddle.net/vorqdkb7/1/

**Dealer**

```
function deal_dealer_cards(){
    let dealerContainer = document.querySelector('.dealer_container');

        let card = deck.pop();
        dealerHand.push(card);

        let dealerCard = document.createElement('div');
        dealerCard.className = "dealer_card";
        dealerContainer.append(dealerCard);

        let rank = document.createElement('div');
        rank.className = "rank";
        dealerCard.append(rank);
        rank.innerHTML = card.value;


        let symbol = document.createElement('div');
        dealerCard.append(symbol);
        symbol.className = 'symbol';

        let cardSymbol = document.createElement('span');
        symbol.append(cardSymbol);
        cardSymbol.setAttribute('id', 'card_symbol');

        let i = document.createElement('i');
        cardSymbol.append(i);
        let fa = "fas ";
```

**Player**

```
function deal_player_cards(){

    let playerContainer = document.querySelector('.player_container');


    let fa = "fas ";

        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            let card = deck.pop();
            playerHand.push(card);


            let playerCard = document.createElement('div');
            playerCard.className = "player_card";
            playerContainer.append(playerCard);

            let rank = document.createElement('div');
            rank.className = "rank";
            playerCard.append(rank);
            rank.innerHTML = card.value;


            let symbol = document.createElement('div');
            playerCard.append(symbol);
            symbol.className = 'symbol';
            let cardSymbol = document.createElement('span');
            symbol.append(cardSymbol);
            cardSymbol.setAttribute('id', 'card_symbol');

            let i = document.createElement('i');
            cardSymbol.append(i);
            let fa = "fas "; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the div `.symbol` does get appended but down below in your code you update the className.

With this code 
`symbol.className = fa + "fa-heart";`

Now I don't know exactly what you would need here. But if you want to append the symbol class maybe you want to do something like

```
symbol.className += " " + fa + "fa-heart";
```

I hope it helps

Comment: ahh completely forgot to check that if statement for the problem ,Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

you can use `symbol.classList.add('fa-heart')` to add class to the element because you did is to override the whole className attribute with the new one.

and you can use `symbol.classList.remove('fa-heart')` to remove a specific class too.

Hope this helps you.